# Can i type cast a long type 1d array element into int?

Tags: java, arrays, foreach, int, long-integer

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long[] longarr = {40, 50, 70, 90};
        int sum = 0;
        for (int x: (int) longarr) {
            sum += x;
        }
        System.out.println("sum is " + sum);
    }
}
```

how could we fix the error without making the long type array to int. is there any way to do so?

Comment: In this case this is pretty obvious but when you ask to fix an error it's better to copy the text of the error.

Comment: They are `long` elements for a reason, think about down casting and what it does to your data before actually casting it.

Comment: Note that it is totally unsafe to cast a sum of `long`s to an `int`. I hope that there are some constraints on those `long`s which prevent the sum to exceed the max value for an `int`.

Answer (score 6):

You have a couple of problems with your code:

1. you cannot cast a `long[]` to an `int[]` like this --> `(int) longarr`, so what you need to do is leave it as `for (int x: longarr) {...}`
2. Given you've changed it to `for (int x: longarr) {...}` a new error arises as the compiler cannot explicitly cast a `long` to an `int` therefore you can change the type of the variable to `for (long x: longarr) {...}`
3. Now you can cast each `long` to an `int` before applying the summation.

This is what @Meini's approach does, but here is another approach anyway:

```
int summation = Arrays.stream(longarr).mapToInt(v -> (int)v).sum();
```

Note that `mapToInt` is required here to actually get the `int` value you require otherwise if we were to assign directly the summation of `long`s to an `int` variable the compiler will complain as a `long` can store much larger values than an `int`.

another version:

```
int summation = (int)Arrays.stream(longarr).sum();
```

Comment: Good answer +1.  You might want to explain the `mapToInt` step and why that avoids the lossy conversion error.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen updated with more info, hopefully, that helps. thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long[] longarr = {40, 50, 70, 90};
    int sum = 0;

    for (long x : longarr) {
        sum += (int)  x;
    }
    System.out.println("sum is " + sum);
}
```

Actually you don't have to explicitly cast `x` to `int` -> `sum += x;`, i  leave it there to make it more clearly

Comment: @MuratKaragöz You can't cast a primitive array to another like `int[] s = new long[0]`, in this case it's even worse because `long[]` was casted into `int`. Although u can cast `Object[] str = new String[0];`

Answer (score 1):

**Your question was must be :**

> how to fix error :     incompatible types: long cannot be converted
>   int

Change in the loop to  :

```
 public class NewClass {  
      public static void main(String[] args) {

            long[] longarr = {40, 50, 70, 90};
            int sum = 0 ; 

            for (long  x: longarr  ) { // don't need cast 
                sum += x;
            }
            System.out.println("sum is " + sum);
        }
         }
```

run:

```
 sum is 250
```

Comment: Walcome to StackOverflow MyPs this is your first answer!

Answer (score 0):

Correct :

```
for (long x : longarr) {

}
```

No need to do an explicit type cast.